# How to switch between Heroku apps (working locally)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have two different apps I'm working on, and have deployed both to heroku. I want to work locally and just view my app at localhost:3000, but how do I switch which app localhost:3000 displays? And how do I specify that each project gets committed/deployed to the right Heroku app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start each app on a different port:

```
$ rails s -p 4000
```

Or use something like [Pow](http://pow.cx/)

When you push to Heroku it will use the folder you're currently in (the remote repo is stored as part of the Git configuration).